# Meteor rawCollection().aggregate returns type error

Tags: meteor

On server side I have following code:

```
Menus = new Mongo.Collection('menus);

Meteor.startup(function() {
    Menus.rawCollection().aggregate([
        {$project: {_id: 1, name: { "$toLower": "$name" } }}
    ]);
});
```

It gives me `TypeError: object is not a function` error

at path `/home/mateusz/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.1.4.39_1.1oqi3la++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246`

I'm using Meteor@1.2.1 with standard mongo 2.6 backed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the aggregate function with the **[`Meteor.wrapAsync()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync)** method which wraps an asynchronous function so you can call it in a synchronous style but you will lose reactivity:

```
wrapAsync = (Meteor.wrapAsync)? Meteor.wrapAsync : Meteor._wrapAsync;
Mongo.Collection.prototype.aggregate = function(pipeline, options) {
    var collection = (this.rawCollection) ? this.rawCollection() : this._getCollection();
    return wrapAsync(collection.aggregate.bind(collection))(pipeline, options);
}

Menus = new Mongo.Collection('menus);
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Menus.aggregate([
        {$project: {_id: 1, name: { "$toLower": "$name" } }}
    ]).forEach(function (doc){ console.log(doc) });
});
```

Comment: As far as I know Meteor.wrapAsync is for wrapping functions that accepts callbacks. As stated here: https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/ aggregate method doesn't accepts callback as a argument. It's last argument is options object. Am I missing sth here?

Comment: You have referenced the mongo shell method, the one `Meteor.wrapAsync` wraps is the underlying native Node.js mongo driver's [**`aggregate()`**](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate) method, which is asynchronous.

Comment: The mongo shell [**`aggregate()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method returns a [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) to the documents produced by the final stage of the aggregation pipeline operation and the [**`forEach()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) is a method that iterates the cursor results, similar to [**`toArray()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray) which returns an array that contains all documents returned by the cursor.

Comment: Ok thanks :) So It means that code like this should also work: `Menus.rawCollection().aggregate([
        {$project: {_id: 1, name: { "$toLower": "$name" } }}
    ], function(err, res) {
        console.log(err, res);
    });`?